# cgo do i need to free the memory for a variable returned by a C function to go

Tags: c, memory-management, go, cgo

I am new to cgo and have a couple of questions to do with memory management.

Say I have a simple c function as below:

```
char* get_str_in_arr(char **charArr, size_t i){
    return charArr[i];
}
```

do i need to free the memory as below:

```
func doSomething(){
    cStr := C.get_str_in_arr(feats, C.size_t(1))
    goStr := C.GoString(cStr)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cStr))
    ...
}
```

If this is the case do I need to do this with any variable returned from a method. For example a c Struct, uint32_t, ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Think of it in terms of C more than in terms of Go. If you're returning (from your C function) a pointer to some allocated (as in `malloc()`) memory — that should be freed (if, of course it's not referenced in some other memory allocated by C code). If you're returning some structure (not a pointer to the structure) or integer — there is nothing to free. If you're returning a pointer to some static memory — that should not be freed.

So in your example it's the question of what `feats` is, how it was allocated, how it is managed. Given the current code it's just impossible to give the definitive answer on whether you need to `free()` the returned value or not.